# $f(x)$ is a polynomial and $f(\alpha)^2+f'(\alpha)^2=0$. Find $\lim_{x\to\alpha}\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}\left\lfloor\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right\rfloor$

Tags: calculus, limits

> $f(x)$ is a polynomial and $f(\alpha)^2+f'(\alpha)^2=0$. Find $$\lim_{x\to\alpha}\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}\left\lfloor\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right\rfloor$$

$f(x)=x^3$ and $\alpha=0$ satisfies the given condition.

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^3}{3x^2}\left\lfloor\frac{3x^2}{x^3}\right\rfloor$$
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{3}\left\lfloor\frac{3}{x}\right\rfloor$$
$\left\lfloor\frac{3}{x}\right\rfloor$ is approx. $\frac{3}{x}$ when $x\to0$
So the answer is $1$. But I need to know the actual method. Maybe I am making some errors in my assumption.

Comment: You cant really differentiate that equation as I suppose it holds only for some $\alpha \in \mathbb R$, and not for all $\alpha$ in some interval.

Comment: @Macavity even without differentiation, $f(x)=x^3$ satisfies the initial condition with $\alpha=0$.

Comment: Sure - but that is only one of the functions which satisfies it for $\alpha = 0$. For e.g. $f(x) = x^4-2x^2+1$ satisfies the condition for $\alpha = 1$ and so on.  I suppose you need to prove for all possible $f$.  Your final limit is correct, the approach however is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From definition of $\lfloor x \rfloor$, we get
$$
1-\left|\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}\right|\le \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}\left\lfloor\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right\rfloor \le 1.
$$
From $f(\alpha)^2+f'(\alpha)^2=0$, $f(\alpha)=f'(\alpha)=0$ and so $f$ has $(x-\alpha)^n$ as a factor for some $n\ge 2$ and $f'$ has $(x-a)^{n-1}$ as a factor. Thus, there exists the polynomial $P(x),Q(x)$ which do not have $\alpha$ as a root such that
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to \alpha} \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}&=\lim_{x\to\alpha}\frac{(x-\alpha)^n P(x)}{(x-\alpha)^{n-1}Q(x)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\alpha}\frac{(x-\alpha)P(x)}{Q(x)}\\
&=\frac{0\cdot P(\alpha)}{Q(\alpha)}\\
&=0.
\end{align}
By squeeze theorem, the proof is over.

Comment: Good approach, but there is a nit - that inequality seems wrong unless you also  assume $f, f'$ have the same sign, which clearly need not be the case.

Comment: @Macavity Oh, I forgot it. But I can't fix it now because I can't use my computer now. Maybe I can do it after a few hours, When returning to home.

Comment: In the interim took the liberty of a small edit, you could modify / expand later.